# Javascript ¿como meter un array asociativo en otro array?

Tags: javascript

Pues eso meter un array asociativo bajo la forma.

```
var tabla[];
tabla['nombre']='Jose';
```

mi codigo es el siguiente:

```js
var regs = [];
var usuario = [];
usuario['nombre'] = 'Jose';
usuario['dni'] = '45875458X';
regs[0] = usuario;

usuario['nombre'] = 'Fernando';
usuario['dni'] = '52487125G';
regs[1] = usuario;
var sx = regs[0].nombre;
var sy = regs[1].nombre;

console.log(sx);
console.log(sy);
```

Cuando muestro los datos resulta que los dos registros en el array regs son idénticos, le he dado mil vueltas y solo lo consigo con un array de objetos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La variable `usuario`, la he cambiado por una función que recibe los parámetros `nombre` y `dni`. Esta función, lo que hace es declarar un array, y luego agregarle las propiedades correspondientes.

Luego, mediante la función `push`, agregar al final de la lista `reg`, cada usuario, llamando a la función `usuario`.

```js
function usuario(nombre,dni)
{
    var array=[]
    array.nombre=nombre
    array.dni=dni
    return array
}
var regs = []
regs.push( usuario('Jose'    ,'45875458X') )
regs.push( usuario('Fernando','52487125G') )
var sx = regs[0].nombre
var sy = regs[1].nombre
console.log(sx)
console.log(sy)
console.log(regs)
```

Answer (score 0):

En JavaScript no existen arrays asociativas, se llaman Objetos. La guía de [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Trabajando_con_objectos) explica muy bien como usarlos y los diferentes métodos que tienen. Para crear un objeto, puedes hacer:

```
const usuario = {};
usuario.nombre = 'Jose';
```

O directamente definir las propiedades del objeto en su propia definición usando:

```
const usuario = {
  nombre: 'Jose',
  dni: '45875458X',
  ...
};
```

A continuación, puedes acceder a estas propiedades usando `usuario.nombre` o `usuario['dni']`, que permite el acceso a claves dinámicas.

Otra cosa, en vez de añadir objetos a una array por índice también puedes usar `array.push(objeto)` que insertará el objeto en la última posición.

Comment: Esa forma ya la conozco cuando ,la llamo array de objetos ,lo que estoy estudiando es la posibilidad de hacerlo solo con arrays

Comment: Las arrays en JavaScript sólo pueden tener índices numéricos, por lo que `const arr = []; arr['texto'] = 'blah';` dará un error. La mejor estructura de datos para lo que has propuesto es una array de objetos.

Comment: @HugoManrique No es correcto, los arrays pueden tener propiedades igualmente que los objetos.

Comment: @ArtEze Sí, pero no es para lo que están diseñadas. Las arrays son objetos, y por ello mismo puedes definir propiedades sobre ellas, pero no añadirán valores a la propia array.

Comment: @HugoManrique Bueno, los agrega pero están ocultos.

Comment: Sí, pero insisto, harás uso de memoria inecesaria usando el tipo de estructura de datos. Una array es una colección de objetos, no un mapa key->value, que es para lo que los objetos están hechos.

Answer (score 0):

De la siguiente manera:

```js
var array = {
  primero:{
    propiedad:"primer_valor1",
    propiedad2:"primer_valor2"
  },
  segundo:{
    propiedad:"segundo_valor1",
    propiedad2:"segundo_valor2"
  }
};
console.log(array);
console.log(array.primero.propiedad);
console.log(array.segundo.propiedad2);
```

Answer (score 0):

espero te sirva el siguiente código:

```js
 usuarios = [];
    
    usuarios.push({
      nombre: 'Jose',
      dni: '45875458X'
    });
    
    usuarios.push({
      nombre: 'Fernando',
      dni: '52487125G'
    });
    
    console.log(usuarios);
    console.log(usuarios[0]);
    console.log(usuarios[0].nombre + ', tiene el DNI: ' + usuarios[0].dni);
```

Comment: Que realiza este código, es importante especificarlo, revisar [answer].